# Updating request timeout on .net framework MVC web app hosted on azure

Tags: .net, azure, model-view-controller, arr

I have an MVC .NET Framework (4.5) web app hosted on azure which is using ARR to implement a reverse proxy to an external API.

It seems as no matter what I try, a long running request returns 502 after exactly 2 minutes with message:

```
The specified CGI application encountered an error and the server terminated the process.
```

I have this set in the web.config

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  </system.web>
```

and have this transform in the site root on azure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration  xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <system.applicationHost>
    <webLimits xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionTimeout)" 
               connectionTimeout="00:05:00" />
  </system.applicationHost>
</configuration>
```

I have verified that the applicationHost.config has the webLimit connectionTimeout set on the server, and have restarted the webapp. However, I **STILL** get 502 after 2 minutes. I can also hit the endpoint directly without timing out after 2 minutes, but through the reverse proxy it stops at 2 minutes every time.

What timeout setting could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Configuring from web.config will not work in Azure app service:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="3600" />
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5.2">
  </system.web>
```

As App service has default time out of 240 Seconds.

In my opinion , you should troubleshoot the sub status code for your request. Status code in this request is 502, look for the sub status code  and troubleshoot further on this.

Looking at the question, it seems application is taking time to respond, which you can bubble down and troubleshoot the actual reason from the azure portal itself by using **`Diagnostic and solve problem`** blade.

In Diagnostic and solve problem , look for the **`Availability and performance`** section and check 5** errors.

hope it helps.